# How can I make a regex for this pattern "(<key><operator><value>)"?

Tags: regex, regex-group

I need to force the entry of information that meets the following pattern:

- Conditioned groups with parentheses
- Inside the parentheses, you can have infinite pairs of key, operator, value - separated by ";" *(AND)* or "," *(OR)*
- Groupers can also be separated by ";" or ","
- The keys meet the same specifications as the json key
- The values, can also be any type of values, as well as json values
- The operators can be: ==, !=, <, >, <=, >=

Example 1:

`(email==test@mail.com;type!=test;schedule==false),(email==test1@mail.com;type==unit)`

Example 2:

`(email!=test@mail.com,schedule==false);(value<=1)`

Trying to do something like this:

`[(][a-zA-Z0-9_](==|>|<|>=|<=|!=)[\w][)]`

But without success.. .

Can I actually do it using regex?

Comment: This is the sort of task where regexes get nigh-indecipherable (and untestable) if you're not a certified wizard. A little hand-written parser with a state machine would be a few more lines of code, but would also be far easier to maintain -- especially if someone gets the bright idea of extending the format. Note that any naive approach will almost certainly fail to respect the idea that things should be valid JSON (and indeed in your example they are not -- no strings are quoted, for starters, and that might well become necessary if they can contain `;` or `,` themselves).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
/^(\((.*?([=!><]=|>|<).*?([;,]|\))*)(,|$))*/i
```